# Express 3 and Jade: "TypeError: Property 'engine' of object #<View> is not a function"

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm new to Express and Jade and I'm getting the following error when rendering a view.

> TypeError: Property 'engine' of object # is not a function

My configuration is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
app.set("views", __dirname + "/../views");
app.set("view engine", "jade");
```

The app crashes on the following rendering function:

```
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
  response.render("game.jade", { message: "this is a variable" });
});
```

The view exists in the views directory and contains just some simple jade test html.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: In which file does the type error occur?

Comment: Remove `.jade` from the file name

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue if you have a file called `jade.js` (or `jade/index.js`) somewhere in your `$NODE_PATH` that's being loaded (and returning an object instead of a function) before the actual Jade package (and/or you haven't installed it).

You can find which file is loaded like this:

```
$ node -e 'console.log(require.resolve("jade"))'
```

Comment: Okay, this is a good to know troubleshooting method and helped me with same problem.  But...how to solve?

Comment: @jdr5ca I think Node will always prefer installed modules (in `./node_modules` or globally installed) over local files that are named similarly, so make sure that the module is installed.